# Calculation using SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Formula used**
This is the formula that I used to calculate
Expressed as a single equation:

```
eGFR = 142 x min(Scr/κ, 1)α x max(Scr/κ, 1)-1.200 x 0.9938Age x 1.012 [if female]

where:

Scr = serum creatinine in mg/dL
κ = 0.7  
α = -0.329  
min(Scr/κ, 1) is the minimum of Scr/κ or 1.0
max(Scr/κ, 1) is the maximum of Scr/κ or 1.0
Age (years)
```

**Code that I tried**

```
select 
   ROUND(141 * power(min(cast(40 as float) / 0.7 ) ,-0.329) * 
     power(max( cast(40 as float) / 0.7 * 1) ,- 1.209) * 0.993 *
     cast(42 as float) * 1.018 ,2) as kidney
```

Correct answer should be 123.

Any clue what I am missing in the query?

Comment: What value are you getting when you run this formula? My first thought would be not to use FLOATs but to use DECIMALs with fixed/known precision (or integers if these values will always be integers)

Comment: MIN/MAX are aggregate functions which acts over a rowset. You need LEAST/GREATEST functions. And you do not need in CAST().

Comment: i got 11 but its wrong the correct answer is 123

Comment: You've tagged SQL Server (an RDBMS) and MySQLi (a PHP library for connecting to MySQL). Why the confusing tags?

Comment: Please, when you substantially change your question after you get an answer, [edit] the question to explain your change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this site](https://www.kidney.org/content/ckd-epi-creatinine-equation-2021) your equation is kinda wrong. Please be sure to add `^` to display the "to the power of".

```
DECLARE @Scr    AS FLOAT       = 40.0;
DECLARE @gender AS VARCHAR(10) = 'female';
DECLARE @age    AS SMALLINT    = 42;
DECLARE @k      AS FLOAT       = CASE WHEN @gender = 'male' THEN 0.9    ELSE 0.7    END;
DECLARE @a      AS FLOAT       = CASE WHEN @gender = 'male' THEN -0.302 ELSE -0.241 END;
DECLARE @factor AS FLOAT       = CASE WHEN @gender = 'male' THEN 1.000  ELSE 1.012  END;

SELECT 142 * POWER(IIF(1 < (@Scr/@k), 1, @Scr/@k), @a)
           * POWER(IIF(1 > (@Scr/@k), 1, @Scr/@k), -1.200)
           * POWER(0.9938, @age)
           * @factor;
```

Also this result is correct since it is calculated in `mg/dl` and your expected value is in `umol/l`

[Here](https://www.wisplinghoff.de/fuer-aerzte/formelsammlung/niere-gfr-nach-ckd-epi-formel-chronic-kidney-disease-epidemiology-collaboration/) is another website (it may be german, but it should do the trick)

Comment: Whether right or wrong, formatting can make code far more readable (and therefore understandable). Well done.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use MIN and MAX, those are aggregate (GROUP BY) functions. It would be good if SQL Server had GREATEST and LEAST functions, but it doesn't yet.

- `IIF(a < b, a, b)` is `LEAST(a,b)`.
- `IIF(a > b, a, b)` is `GREATEST(a,b)`.

Don't sweat the CASTs.

Make no assumptions about operator precedence ( x before +, etc). Use parentheses.

Here's a rewrite of what I believe your formula should be. But I'm not getting the right answer yet either.

```sql
DECLARE @Scr AS INT   = 40;
DECLARE @k   AS FLOAT = 0.7;
DECLARE @a   AS FLOAT = -0.329;
DECLARE @age AS INT   = 42;
DECLARE @gender AS VARCHAR(MAX) = 'female';
DECLARE @factor AS FLOAT = CASE WHEN @gender = 'male' THEN 1.0 ELSE 1.012 END;
SELECT   142 
       + (IIF(1 < @Scr/@k, 1, @Scr/@k) * @a)
       * (IIF(1 > @Scr/@k, 1, @Scr/@k))
       - (1.2 * 0.993 * @age * @factor);
```

I obviously misunderstood your formula, but this should get you started. Here's a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=0025c78e3d4fd780f6444d728e3497ac).

Comment: *" It would be good if SQL Server had GREATEST and LEAST functions, but it doesn't yet."* As an FYI, Azure SQL services *do* have [`GREATEST`](//learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-greatest-transact-sql) and [`LEAST`](//learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-least-transact-sql) and the functions are also in SQL Server 2022 (which at the time of this comment is in preview).